# How to concatenate many vectors in one matrix (each vector is a column of the new matrix)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, concatenation

I have for simplicity 4 vectors (type of numpy.ndarray) each of size 256 and I want to create a new matrix where each column correspond to each vector. So after concatenation I will have a 256 * 4 matrix

I tried either using hstack or np.concatenate but I don't get the result I want..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`vstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html) and transpose [`T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T):

```
n = 256
a = np.arange(n) + 0
b = np.arange(n) + 1
c = np.arange(n) + 2
d = np.arange(n) + 3

x = np.vstack([a,b,c,d]).T
x
```

Output:

```
array([[  0,   1,   2,   3],
       [  1,   2,   3,   4],
       [  2,   3,   4,   5],
       ...,
       [253, 254, 255, 256],
       [254, 255, 256, 257],
       [255, 256, 257, 258]])
```

Or, alternatively, there is a [`column_stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.column_stack.html) method as well:

```
x = np.column_stack([a,b,c,d])
```

And if you want to get it as an actual `matrix` instead of `ndarray`:

```
m = np.matrix([a,b,c,d]).T
```

**Update:**
To do it with a loop you can collect your arrays in a list and then stack them together:

```
n = 256
l = []
for i in range(4):
    l.append(np.arange(n) + i)

x = np.vstack(l).T
x
```

Or, alternatively, stack them one-by-one on every step of the loop and transpose after the loop:

```
n = 256
x = np.arange(n)
for i in range(1,4):
    x = np.vstack([x, np.arange(n) + i])

x = x.T
x
```

Comment: `np.stack` can also be used (with axis=1).  They all do the same thing - expand the dimensions of all inputs, and concatenate.

Comment: Hi @perl can you give me an example where do this  in a for loop? i.e., how to concatenate because i want to do the same process with different lengths ..

for example x = np.vstack([a1, a1, ..., a10]).T if i want 10 columns

Comment: @Er1Hall: Sure, please see the Update section of my answer

Comment: Repeated `vstack` is slower.

Comment: Yes, I timed it as well, and put the option with better performance first. I have included the second option, however, for the case if OP's interested in operating on the matrix inside the loop itself